# Jquery-ui Drag and drop. Dropped list contain Dynamically created text box which is not able to edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Dynamically created text box not editable in JQuery UI.. Used Drag and drop option While dropping the item added Text box along with item. But the Text box is not editable.
Text box not editable in Firefox. Chrome works fine.
Any idea will be great help. Please share different approach which will full fill requirement.

jsfiddle.net/dsriniudt/xxndahs2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dsriniudt/xxndahs2/

Comment: When I try the fiddle the textbox is editable. Please explain

Comment: @srinivasanD I suspect you mean to allow user to change the items label. As it is now, when you drop the item, text box is appended and is editable. Looks like you want to allow this when user clicks on label. Is this correct?

Comment: @user7491506 Chrome works fine. But issue in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, we're going to allow the label to be edited after it has been dropped. Once done, it should be saved back as the label.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xxndahs2/6/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable, .connectedSortable1"
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#sortable2").droppable({
    cancel: "#addCustomTitle",
    disabled: false,
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      // Use class 'cutomLabel' to identify labels that can be edited
      ui.draggable.addClass("customLabel");
    }
  });

  $("#sortable2").on("click", ".customLabel", function(e) {
    console.log("Click capture, opening Text Box.");
    // Capture current text
    var currentLabel = $(this).text();
    // Replace current HTML with Input field
    $(this).html($("<input>", {
      class: "entryField",
      type: "text",
      value: currentLabel
    }));
    // Set focus inside input field
    $(this).find("input").focus();
    return false;
  });

  $("#sortable2").on("blur keypress click", ".entryField", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    switch (true) {
      case e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER:
      case e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.TAB:
      case e.originalEvent == "blur":
      case e.type == "focusout":
        console.log("Leaving field or Enter was struck, saving value.");
        // Capture value of input field
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        // Replace HTML with text
        $(this).parent().html(currentValue);
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

So you may wish to change how the "save" happens. You could add button, but I suspect that you were looking for clicking or navigating away type model. So if the user hits <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd> or they click off the input, it will save the current value.

Comment: thanks for the comments.. I was looking for editable text box only. Thanks for great help

Comment: @srinivasanD did you try sorting it after dropping it? Every time you drop it, it appends another textbox.